# Batch File Changing Google Chrome Homepage

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

As title i have already have the combination of ie and ff batch file which function to change ie and firefox homepage but now i am seeking for google chrome.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but a tool on how to figure this out..  Download the following - http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/ make a change to the home page in Google Chrome and compare the before and after..  It should point you to a location like: HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome and it should give you an idea of where to go with this using REG from a command-line.

Comment: Okay bro let me take a try hold on few min

Comment: i found but can't manage to use it

Comment: Can you post the result here?